# MySQL - DateTime from certain point in time till end of that day

Tags: mysql

I've been trying to create a query that gathers all rows from a certain datetime, till the end of that specific day. Is this possible in some neat way?

Comment: use `between` in your query. eg for `SELECT users.* FROM users 
WHERE created_at >= '2016-10-04 00:00:00' 
AND created_at <= '2016-10-04 00:00:00'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this replace date base on your requirement.

```
SELECT users.* FROM users WHERE date(created_at) = date('2016-10-04 10:12:10') and created_at >='2016-10-04 10:12:10'
```

Comment: But this would give every record for an entire day, right? My need is: from a certain timestamp (say 2016-03-10 00:10:23) till the end of that perticular day (in this case, 2016-03-10 23:59:59)

Comment: If you are giving '2016-10-04 00:00:00' then it will give all data which 'created_at' date is since '2016-10-04 00:00:00' to '2016-10-04 23:59:59'